# Style error after importing SLD of QGIS in GeoServer Layer

Tags: web, geoserver, qgis, wms, sld

I have a layer in GeoServer which opens when default style like "polygon" is selected in the publishing menu

[Layer opening with default style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxIHY.png)

but when I change its style in WMS Settings, for which I have created a new style by importing the SLD of same dateset from QGIS,
it shows the error like,

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision
and the layer does not open.

[error with new SLD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyYSD.png)

However while Validating the imported SLD, no errors were encountered.

[validation of New SLD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxcvF.png)

The SLD used is as follows:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 10</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 10</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#440154</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>11 - 20</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>11 - 20</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#24868e</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>21 - 30</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>21 - 30</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#5dc962</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>31 - 40</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>31 - 40</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#8fd744</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>41 - 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>41 - 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e120</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>> 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>> 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>55</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e4e419</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

How to rectify this error.

Comment: cross post of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382469/style-error-after-importing-sld-of-qgis-in-geoserver-layer

Comment: Thought Geographic Information System and  
Stack Overflow are different platforms, so I put the question here too. Still not sure about it though. @IanTurton

Comment: They are different though we still discourage cross posting - in this GIS was the correct place to ask